# dependencies of current namespace

Tags: clojure, namespaces

`*ns*` returns a namespace, not a namespace declaration. `clojure.tools.namespace.parse.deps-from-ns-decl` requires a declaration. There are many ways to read declarations from files. How do I get the declaration from the current namespace (`*ns*`). If this helps, here's what the REPL coughs up:

```
(deps-from-ns-decl *ns*)
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Namespace  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:542)
```

Comment: You may not be able to. `ns` looks like syntax, but it's really a macro that calls things like `require` under the covers. Depending on what you need, some relevant information is available from the `ns-map` and `ns-aliases` functions.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe there's a way to find the source file of the current namespace?

Comment: I don't think you can from the namespace itself, as it's really a very dynamic thing. But many functions are defined in source files, and when they are the associated var (namespace entry) has some metadata telling you about it. So you could do something like

`(->> (vals (ns-publics *ns*)) (map (comp :file meta)) (into #{}))`

Comment: @RussellMull Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that asking questions like this one arises out of "meta" namespace work. In conjunction with Tawny OWL ontology definitions, my app rides on top of Clojure's namespace thinking. To answer my question, I had to create a sense of namespace in the app with it's own dependency declarations. Substrate namespace constructs are just that.